# does django tag '{% url %}' support a context variable for url arguments?

Tags: django, tags

Not sure if I can do the following thing, my url conf likes below:

```
(r'^web/p/(?P<user_info>\w{1,10})/$','web_user_handler')
```

My view render a template kind of likes below:

```
def web_user_handler(request,user_info="temp"):
    render_items=RequestContext(request,{
        'user':user_info,
    })
    return render_to_response('user_index.html', render_items)
```

In my template

```
<a href="{% url pro.web.views.web_user_handler user_info=user %}?action=decoder">
```

But I will get a error then, it said the user_info is equal to a SimpleLazyObject, thus failed to get the url address.

How can I get it out of this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: I finally pass a dict object instead of string object, and then the code starts to work. I will use this method in my template later. This question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

> > But I will get a error then, it said the user_info is equal to a SimpleLazyObject, thus failed to get the url address.

This answers the question: you can't have a python object in a URL!

Is user_info a username? Then pass in `user.username`.

Comment: user_info is a just string object.

Comment: I know I can not have a python object in url, i'm thing about url tag can not get the variable value when rendering a template. is it correct?

Comment: It deals with context variables correctly on my 1.4 and 1.3 and I don't see anything in the docs suggesting otherwise.. Well, I'm glad you got your solution. Hopefully somebody else can figure it out then!